# 1d array of unique distances between points

Tags: java, arrays

I'm coding an N-body simulator with planets (points). I've got it working but there are still a lot of possible optimizations, one of them is to calculate distances between points once and store them in an array. I could use a 2d array (needed to be converted to 1d because the GPU doesn't support 2d arrays) but there are two problems:

1. The simulation would be limited to √2147483647 (max integer value) planets = 46340 planets since the size of the array would be n^2 (n is the number of planets)
2. A lot of the distances would be repeated (distance between 0 and 1 is the same as distance between 1 and 0)

To get the amount of unique connections the formula is: D = (n*(n-1))/2
But now I've got a problem: how to get an index in the distances array given two planet id-s (x,y). The distance index between planet 0 and 1 is 0, 0-2 -> 1, 1-2 -> 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help visualize what this looks like, here is a table showing which index (in the 1D array) corresponds to each pair of planet ids.  To use this table, given a pair of planet ids, find the row that corresponds to the larger of the two ids, and the column that corresponds to the smaller of the two ids, and that will give you the cell with the index of where that distance is stored in your 1D array.

[image]

So, now we need a formula that is given two planet ids and computes the 1D index number.  For simplicity, we will assume that the larger planet id is given first.  (If not, then we can simply swap the two planet ids.)

The first job is to take the larger planet id and determine the first index on its row.  In other words, we need to convert 1 to 0, 2 to 1, 3 to 3, 4 to 6, 5 to 10, 6 to 15, etc.  Luckily, the pattern 0,1,3,6,10,15 is well known - it is the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  The usual formula for the Nth triangular number is (n*(n+1))/2 but in this case we actually want the N-1th triangular number, so the formula we want is `(n*(n-1))/2`.

Once we have the first index of the row, we can just add the smaller planet id to get the final index.

So, our final formula is:

```
 given A (larger planet id) and B (smaller planet id):
 the index of dist(A,B) in the 1D array is ((A * (A-1)) / 2) + B
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
Just a note to people who come around this post:
In the table given, the A id is the y axis and the B id is the x axis, it doesn't work the other way around.